# How to dynamically update available custom transformations list in ArcGIS Pro toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, toolbox

I am in the process of creating a custom toolbox with ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3. In that toolbox, I have two tools :

- Tool A : it creates a custom geographic transformation. I used the tool "Create Custom Geographic Transformation". The resulting .gtf file is automatically created in folder "C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\ArcToolbox\CustomTransformations"
- Tool B : it converts a layer from projection 1 to projection 2. I used the tool "Project" and set "Geographic Transformation" as a parameter.

The goal : when the user opens Tool B, he must be able to select a transformation among several custom ones in a dropdown list.

Several strange things occurred during tests.

- Bug 1 : if I run Tool A and create a custom transformation (let's call it CT1), when I open Tool B right after, I do not see CT1 in the dropdown list.
- Bug 2 : I don't know how, but at some point I did have a dropdown list (I could not repeat this phenomenon since then). I shared the ArcGIS Pro project with other users, and when they opened it, they could create their own transformations with Tool A, but when opening Tool B, they could only see MY transformations, and not their owns. It's like the toolbox had saved my transformations...

There must be some parameter somewhere to dynamically update the transformation dropdown list.

Has someone ever seen this phenomenon and someone know how to dynamically update the dropdown list ?